# Could someone please explain the following Ruby code to me in detail?

Tags: ruby

I nearly had this challenge on Code Wars in the bag but, I blew it because my knowledge of `gsub` is sub-par at best. While I roughly understand the concept of `gsub`, I would like a more thorough understanding of it (different ways you can use it could be helpful to my development) as well as a bit by bit explanation of the code below.

```
def autocorrect(input)
  input.gsub(/\b(you+|u)\b/i, 'your sister')
end
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While you'll see questions asking us to explain how code works on SO, those questions are off-topic. Instead, read the documentation for Regular Expressions in the [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html) class and you can piece it together. Also, web resources like [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/gK9bM2/1) can help. [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) is a very basic building block when doing string manipulation, so knowing how it works is extremely important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking any string that contains a match to the regular expression shown and replacing it with the second parameter which is in this case, "your sister".  Regular expressions are a bit tricky in Ruby but essentially that regular expression is saying:

```
    /   #starts the reg exp
    \b  #any word boundary
    (you+|u)   #the word 'you' with one or more of the letter 'u' added after it (so youuuuu would fit) or just the letter 'u' alone with a 'y' or 'o'... the pipe symbol is an or statement in reg-exp. taking one or the other for a match.  
    \b  #again finishing a word boundary
    /   #closes the expression.
```

Checkout Rubular for tips.  http://rubular.com/

Comment: Regular expressions in general are not easy to master. Regular expressions in Ruby are no more difficult than in other languages.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. This was very clarifying. I am going to study it a bunch. I have basically been doing the coding challenges the best I can. If I fail to complete them, I move on to the answers. If the answers don't make sense to me by looking at the Ruby docs, I move onto stack exchange. I had no idea that it wasn't ok to put questions on here if they were too simple. Sorry guys. I'm still a noob.